# Installing node.js packages for different architecture

Tags: npm

I need to install npm packages that are for a different target architecture (Linux x64) than the machine I am running npm from (Windows x86).  Is there a way to tell `npm install` to download packages that are for the other OS/architecture?

Comment: Can you name an example package?

Answer (score 18):

Most native node modules use [`node-pre-gyp`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp) which uses an install script to search for pre-built binaries for your OS/arch/v8 ABI combination, and fallback to native build if one is not available.

Assuming your native modules use `node-pre-gyp`, you can do this:

```
npm i --target_arch=x64 --target_platform=linux
```

You'll see something like this in the output:

```
> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /home/user/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[bcrypt] Success: "/home/user/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
```

If it can't find a prebuilt binary, `node-pre-gyp` will fall back to attempting to build the module from source.

If the prebuilt modules aren't downloadable, there's also a way to build & host them from your own mirror, but that's a different question :)

Comment: "target_arch" and "target_platform" seem to be options for node-pre-gyp but i don't see them in npm's documentation. I tested cross installing from darwin to linux with these options for npm but it still installed darwin packages.

Answer (score 6):

Most binary npm packages compile the `.node` binary from source. You can't really force cross-compilation with npm, but you can possibly create a [postinstall script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to recompile the particular dependency that re-runs `node-gyp` with an `--arch` flag:

`"postinstall" : "node-gyp -C node_modules/your-dependency clean configure --arch=x86_64 rebuild"`

You will need a proper compiler toolchain. I'm sot sure what it is for windows, but probably you'll end up using [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: I need node-wrtc module for arm v7 architecture. Is it worth trying to download wrtc source in Linux-64 bit PC and the above said node-gyp ?

Answer (score 3):

Since ~2022 it seems that there are new flags to install architecture/os specific packages using `npm`.

[`--cpu`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install#cpu) and [`--os`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install#os), both links to their documentation.

They are both linked to package.json [`os`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#os) and [`cpu`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#cpu) parameters.

Example:

```
npm i --cpu arm64 --os darwin
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the package is electron, you can by

```
npm install --arch=x64 electron
```

or

```
export npm_config_arch=x64
npm install --arch=x64 electron
```

as described on https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation.
These are options of the [electron-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-download) package which downloads the actual binary. So they will work only for electron.

Comment: This was apparently not fully working on AppleARM devices until late December 2021: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/32266

Comment: this was the only way I was able to install electron on a legacy codebase (using electron v4) on my M1 macbook