# How can I force node to download packages for a specific architecture?

Tags: npm-install, apple-m1, lerna, parallels

**Context on my setup:**
I am using Mac M1 and am running windows through parallels.
When running npm install the default package that is being downloaded is ia32 architecture and as far as I know parallels does not support x64 windows however x64 programs can be run on the ia32 architecture with no issues.

The package I am trying to download is from a custom repository and has no ia32 package build.

I am aware of commands such as npm install --arch=x64 and this works great however I am trying to bootstrap using lerna and would like to override the downloading dependencies step in lerna to use x64 packages

Is there a way to force node to install x64 packages through modifying the package.json or through another means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing node.js packages for different architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961623/installing-node-js-packages-for-different-architecture)

Comment: No as I am stuck on the lerna command now which defaults npm install. As far as I know I cannot tell lerna to target a specific architecture