# Ignore npm installation requirements (OS, CPU Architecture, gyp script)

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I'm making a Node.js server for Raspberry Pi. I need to control hardware of it so I need specific library I found from NPM repo.

Package name is 'array-gpio' and when seeing it's `package.json`
It requires Linux on ARM (or ARM x64) to install it.

I found that there are C programming language code and it's header in it. And gyp script runs C compiler.

I'm doing my job on Windows 11 for testing, and plan to configure Raspberry Pi after all code is complete. (No Raspberry Pi machine at the moment, and I doubt if it is enough RAM to build server code.)

I tried install it, `npm` message are like below,

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for array-gpio@1.7.2: wanted {"os":"linux","cpu":"arm,arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","cpu":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual os:  win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid cpu:  arm,arm64
npm ERR! notsup Actual cpu: x64
```

The problem is, I will not run package's code from my own Windows computer, I just need to import it for build working code for HW control. But NPM reject to install. (I need to build the code and integrate with my existing code with the package.)

Is there any way to install it without running `gyp` script and with ignoring OS, architecture requirements?

I tried `npm install --ignore-scripts`, but it does not ignore package.json requirements (OS, arch).

Comment: Workaround: run `npm install` on the raspberry pi instead of your PC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing node.js packages for different architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961623/installing-node-js-packages-for-different-architecture)

Comment: @Konrad I checked that before, it seems answer talking about alternative toolchain to bulild it. But there are no alternative for windows in this case. What I just need is it's type and function linting in this case regardless of if it is working or not on Windows(I'll even not run that packages code on the windows. (And i don't have raspberry py but assuming it can be installed on raspberry pi os)